# Dereference a HTML::Element hash reference

Tags: perl, dereference

I'm looping through an array that has stored some values from `HTML::TreeBuilder`, where a `look_down()` was used. When I `print $value`, I get the below, which I would like dereferenced.

```
HTML::Element=HASH(0xe687f4)
```

Doing a print `\$value` seems to return a generic reference:

```
REF(0xe6ea84)
```

What is the symbol/s I need to dereference a HTML::Element hash reference?

Note:
Using `$$value` returns error `Not a SCALAR reference`

EDIT: Solution found thanks to cjm via comments. I needed print `$value->as_HTML`

Comment: If its a reference then try using $$value. Better post the code so that i can look over it for better help.

Comment: What output are you expecting to get?  Are you looking for `$value->as_HTML`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have an object (indicated by the "HTML::Element" part of `HTML::Element=HASH(0xe687f4)`), you should normally access it only through its documented interface.  For [HTML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aElement), important methods include `as_HTML` (which returns the element and its content as a string of HTML code) and `dump` (which prints a summary of the contents and is useful for debugging).

So, if you want to print the HTML you've extracted, use:

```
print $value->as_HTML;
```